# C++ server applications

Tags: c++, language-agnostic

Could someone point to preferred references/books for `C++` or `language-agnostic` **server application development**?

*I do have some experience in this sphere, but I would like to know more and, obviously, knowledge may come from reading the corresponding books :)*

Comment: That's not about some application I'm developing, but just about good references. I'm pretty sure there is a lot to read :)

Comment: that's way to broad term from me. web(html) application? finance? erp? game server engine? database? ...

Comment: Well, basically for me a server application is something that allows the client-side to send specific request and retrieve the requested data as fast as possible.

Comment: also look into Thrift (http://diwakergupta.github.com/thrift-missing-guide/) or protobuf (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) - being able to plug in clients/servers written in any (supported) language helps with learning these language-agnostic principles ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the main related topics:

- Networking
- Disk I/O
- Concurrency
- Scaling
- High availability and fault tolerance

For networking: Stevens' Unix network programming bible is a very good *starting point* (if you mix it with his TCP Illustrated book you will also get a deep understanding of the topic), but after that you have to dig the net for recent articles.

I personally found that the best sources for fast applications (>1k concurrent clients, heavy disk i/o, caching, concurrency, MVCC, locking and synchronizing, lock free algorithms and data structures, scalable systems) are on the net, mainly blogs and collected articles. Digging into the source code of some cool open source projects is also invaluable.

As I said that's my experience but I would like to here about any really good books covering one or more of these topics.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn about sockets and the server side of that, try Stevens, *Network Programming*.

[http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Network-Programming-Networking-Sockets/dp/013490012X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1310677130&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013490012X)

Comment: I love how you managed to skip the all-caps UNIX in the title.

Answer (score 1):

[Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) is a classic.

Answer (score 0):

There is few good books on the ACE C++ framework developed by Douglas C. Schmidt, for example [C++ Network Programming: Resolving Complexity Using ACE and Patterns v.1: Resolving Complexity Using ACE and Patterns Vol 1](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Network-Programming-Resolving-Complexity-Patterns/dp/0201604647/ref=pd_sim_b_1)